# iPhone - calling a method from the top view controller

Tags: iphone

I have 3 viewController classes, A, B and C.

From class A, I push and present class B and then from class B I push and present class C. All classes have delegate protocols defined, so

- b.delegate = a
- c.delegate = b

Now I am inside class C, but I need to run a method from class A.

What is the best way to call that method? I mean the best practice.

I can imagine declaring this on B

```
- (BOOL) myMethodOnA {
// this method on B will run the method on A and return it to C
   return [delegate myMethodOnA];
}
```

but this sounds to me like a bad solution.

Any suggestions?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might miss something obvious but shouldn't this work?

`[c.delegate.delegate myMethodOnA]`

Also get into the habit of using accessors (make sure you don't take ownership of delegates). ARC makes this so much better.

Comment: can you give an example on how you would do that using accessors? Thanks

Comment: That code is using delegates. You had in your original code but didn't make the connection between them so I kinda assumed that you don't understand them fully.

Comment: the problem is that I did not understand your phrase "make sure you don't take ownership of delegates"... what does that mean. Do you care to elaborate more on the theme? Thanks

Comment: Sure. The short answer is don't retain the delegate as part of the @property declaration. The long answer is here: http://etcshadow.wordpress.com/2010/04/17/objective-c-and-the-delegate-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to run on class A.

One easy option is to Observe for a notification in class A and post the notification from class C

Refer: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: yes, but how I receive the results back? Suppose this method on A needs to return a value to C. I think notifications will make it much more complex.